# (Chrome Extension) Execute something from extension before page addEventListener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want to add `" HELLO"` to a message box before the message is sent (when press <kbd>enter</kbd>).

Example:
Here I try to change the whole message to  (current message + " HELLO") to the message box when the user press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>(return key).

Code (example for slack message box):

```
document.querySelector('.ql-editor').addEventListener("keydown", async function(event) {

    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        //Fetch current element with data
        var slackMessageField = document.querySelector('.ql-editor');

        event.preventDefault();

        textRightNow = slackMessageField.innerText;
        slackMessageField.innerText = (slackMessageField.innerText + " HELLO");
    }
});
```

```
slackMessageField = `<div class="ql-editor ql-blank" data-gramm="false" 
   contenteditable="true" id="undefined" dir="auto" role="textbox" tabindex="0"
   data-team-id="T9L8N47PZ" aria-label="Message #ipnmod"
   aria-describedby="context-bar-text" aria-multiline="true"
   aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false"
   aria-owns="chat_input_tab_ui" spellcheck="true"><p><br></p></div>`
```

which is where the user types the message in.

Problem:
Slack sends the regular message before adding " HELLO" and also don't manage to fetch the current innerText (textRightNow).
So we end up with "(EMPTY SPACE) HELLO" in the message box instead of adding " HELLO".

Comment: What does your `slackMessageField` contain at the beginning?

Comment: slackMessageField = `<div class="ql-editor ql-blank" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true" id="undefined" dir="auto" role="textbox" tabindex="0" data-team-id="T9L8N47PZ" aria-label="Message #ipnmod" aria-describedby="context-bar-text" aria-multiline="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="chat_input_tab_ui" spellcheck="true"><p><br></p></div>` which is where the user types the message in.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior may be happening just because the element `slackMessageField` doesn't have any text inside of it and thus `slackMessageField.innerText` isn't getting any text. If you happen to run the same event over and over, you'll have the `<space>Hello` concatinated every time. Please make sure that you've added the text that you're searching is available inside the targeted element. For instance:

```js
document.querySelector('.ql-editor').addEventListener("keydown", async function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    //Fetch current element with data
    var slackMessageField = document.querySelector('.ql-editor');

    event.preventDefault();

    textRightNow = slackMessageField.innerText;
    slackMessageField.innerText = (slackMessageField.innerText + " HELLO");
  }
});
```

```css
.ql-editor {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<label>Press Enter:</label>
<div class="ql-editor ql-blank" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true" id="undefined" dir="auto" role="textbox" tabindex="0" data-team-id="T9L8N47PZ" aria-label="Message #ipnmod" aria-describedby="context-bar-text" aria-multiline="true" aria-autocomplete="list"
  aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="chat_input_tab_ui" spellcheck="true">
  Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

On the above example, when the keydown event triggers, there will be some existing text inside the `slackMessageField` element, and thus the result will show as `Lorem Ipsum HELLO` after the event has triggered.

Comment: The code works as intended, but the problem here Is that the website where the message box is gets cleared before we have the time to fetch the current message with the extention. I need to execute the eventListner before the website sends the message and clears the box. You will understand the problem if you add another eventlistner that clears the box before you add " hello"

Comment: If some native(inside) script clears out the content, then that can't be helped as the site script will always triggers first before we do any modifications to the page using external script(in this case chrome extension).

Comment: Alright, Is it possible to block that function through extension somehow? Sorry for asking here!

Comment: Never mind! Figured it out, everytime a character changes inside the messagebox, I'll save it to the variable! :D

Answer (score 0):

There Is no way to do this.
Site runs a script before which clears the messagebox.
I'll have to save the content of the messagebox everytime it changes.